# Libre Calc not respecting custom fields

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I have an .xlsx file that has some custom date/time formatted columns.  Specifically, I have 2 columns that have custom format of yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ssZ

When I open it in LibreOffice Calc, the dates in those 2 columns show as decimal numbers instead, eg. 44778.6423148148

If I open the document in Excel Online, everything looks as it should.  If I change the format of those 2 columns within Calc using the same format of yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ssZ, they change just fine.

I also wanted to add that I am exporting this file from PowerBi so I don't have the option to save it in an older format of excel.

How can I have it retain the formatting when opening the file in Calc?

Comment: I also wanted to add that I am exporting this file from PowerBi so I don't have the option to save it in an older format of excel.  Thanks.

Comment: You might have found a "gap" in the XLSX importer of Calc or have used an incompatible format string. For example my Excel and LibreOffice need "JJJJ" instead of "yyyy" (upper case and another letter) for the year because of the applications' user language. Oh, and with adjusted format, it works for me with Excel of Office 2016 and LibreOffice 7.3.1.3.